# Resolving a double many-to-many relationship

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

I have the following database design between entities. [image: ER diagram]

A **Student** can belong to many **Departments** and a **Department** has many **Students**. A specific **Department** has many **Courses** and one **Course** can be at many **Departments**. However, the course has a different relevance value depending on which department it belongs to. The **Student** have grades on specific courses on specific departments. How should I create the relationships that the Student can have grade attribute?

The many-to-many tables are now like this:

```
| Student ID | Department ID |
| 1          | 1             |
| 1          | 2             |
| 2          | 1             |
| 2          | 2             |
```

======================================

```
| Department ID | Course ID | Relevance |
| 1             | 1         | 5         |
| 1             | 2         | 10        |
| 2             | 1         | 11        |
| 2             | 2         | 4         |
```

Is it OK if I make a primary key at the many-to-many table between the **Department** and **Course** and I connect the **Student** entity there, as in the image below? And this will lead to something like:

```
| Student ID | Department ID | Course ID | Relevance | Grade |
| 1          | 1             | 1         | 5         | 5     |
| 1          | 1             | 2         | 10        | 7     |
| 1          | 2             | 1         | 11        | 8     |
| 1          | 2             | 2         | 4         | 10    |
| 2          | 1             | 1         | 4         | 10    |
| 2          | 1             | 2         | 3         | 9     |
| 2          | 2             | 1         | 6         | 9     |
| 2          | 2             | 2         | 7         | 9     |
```

[image]